# Not able to add embedded Tomcat server in maven webapp type project in visual studio codes

Tags: java, maven, servlets, web-applications

I am new to java servlets and I am trying to use an embedded tomcat server to run my servlets. I have added this plugin in POM.XML. I am ***using Visual Studio Codes***.

```xml
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <port>9090</port>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I am trying to run the command ***mvn clean install*** to compile the project with the tomcat plugin. Then this error keeps coming.

```
PS F:\Project2020\ServletsInVSCode\servletdemo> mvn clean install
mvn : The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mvn clean install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mvn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have no idea to solve this issue. Somebody, please help me here. I know many questions have been asked regarding embedded tomcat in maven projects but none of them has the issue same as mine.

Comment: Is Maven actually installed and accessible? See also [some or all of these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvn+is+not+recognized+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: Hi @andrewjames, Do I need to download and install maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi ? Maven in my VSCode ide won't work?

Comment: I don't use VSCode, so I don't know how it integrates with Maven. But the error is clear: the `mvn` command is "not recognized". So, either Maven is not installed, or it is installed but not configured correctly for VS Code to use. That could be as simple as a missing environment variable. Or it could be something else.